# How to hide a Tab when the user is logged in / not logged in

Tags: tabs, woocommerce

Woocommerce Tab manager

I want to hide a specific tab on the single product page depending on if the user is logged in or logged out

```
/*Remove appraisel tab when not logged in */
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'sb_woo_remove_appraisal_tab', 98);
function sb_woo_remove_appraisal_tab($tabs) {

    if (is_user_logged_in()
    unset($tabs['get-this-item-appraised']);

    elseif (!is_user_logged_in()
    return $tabs;
}
```

What am I doing wrong? any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Bit syntax plus login error. Try this code :

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'sb_woo_remove_appraisal_tab', 98);
function sb_woo_remove_appraisal_tab($tabs) {
//If you dont want to show non-logged in users
    if (!is_user_logged_in())
    unset($tabs['get-this-item-appraised']);
    return $tabs;

//if you dont want to show logged in users

    if (is_user_logged_in())
    unset($tabs['get-this-item-appraised']);
    return $tabs;
}
```

Use any one of this if according to your requirement.